# Updating object value in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have objects list and I cannot collect all updates at once.

`Code`

```
let answers = {};

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    var chatId = 1245454; // unique for each user
    var text = msg.text; // input text by user

    answers[chatId] = {
        name: '',
        symbol: ''
    }
    
    // if user type `a` we set name to `sam` (for testing purpose only)   
    if(text = 'a') {
        answers[chatId].name = 'sam';
    }

    // if user type `b` we set symbol to `@` (for testing purpose only)
    if(text = 'b') {
        answers[chatId].symbol = '@';
    }
}
```

Final look of `answers` will be like:

```
answers = {
    1245454: {
        name: 'sam',
        symbol: '@'
    },
    222222: {
        name: 'Tom',
        symbol: '!'
    },
    // and so on...
};
```

`Issue`

The issue is when I update `symbol`, `name` value will beck to it's default and become `name: '',`

`example`

```
// updating name
answers = {
    1245454 {
        name: 'sam',
        symbol: ''
    },
};

// updating symbol
answers = {
    1245454 {
        name: '',
        symbol: '@'
    },
};

// supposed to be
answers = {
    1245454 {
        name: 'sam',
        symbol: '@'
    },
};
```

**Any suggestion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the existence of `answers[chatId]` before creating the new, blank object.

```
if (!answers[chatId]) {
  answers[chatId] = {
    name: '',
    symbol: ''
  }
}
```

This will leave the existing `answers` objects for updates.